# CanCanCan User edit his own profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

I got a really strange issue here. Here is the line causing all the trouble in my `ability.rb`

```
    can [:edit, :update, :destroy], User, id: user.id
```

When I launch the rails console, I got the expected behaviour:

```
u = User.last
a = Ability.new(u)
a.can?(:edit, u)
=> true
a.can?(:edit, User.first)
=> false
```

However when I launch a web browser, log me in as a user and try to edit another one, CanCanCan remains silent.
If I replace `can` by `cannot`, I can't edit any user. It's as if it didn't lookup the condition.

My `UsersController` got this line on top

```
authorize_resource
```

I'm stuck with this, any help would be gladly appreciated.

cancancan 2.3.0
rails 5.2.1

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Try to show full code that reproduces the problem, not a description of the code. Is it possible that, for example, you have some additional logic in the `Ability` that sometimes overrides this definition? Or maybe a different `Ability` class is being used? Or maybe `authorize_resource` has been overridden? The error could be caused by all manor of things, and without a full reproduction example I have no way of knowing for sure.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your rails server? I can't remember for sure if you need to after making changes to `ability.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your instance (`@user`) is loaded before `authorize_resource` action runs, otherwise it will check if user can *access some Users* (`can?(:edit, User)`, which is always true), instead of exact user.

```
before_action :load_user, except:[:index, :new, :create]
authorize_resource

...

private def load_user
  @user = User.accessible_by(current_ability, action_name.to_sym).find(params[:id])
end
```